# ImportError: cannot import name 'ArticleSerializer' from 'basics.serializers'

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

while working with serializers in Django Shell I had to import from basics.serializers import ArticleSerializer the error I'm getting is :

P.S. I'm a beginner at the rest framework of Django

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 from basics.serializers import ArticleSerializer

ImportError: cannot import name 'ArticleSerializer' from 'basics.serializers' (C:\Users\Sony\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Frameworks of python\django\django_rest_framework\basics\serializers.py)

basics\serializer.py
the code for the serializer.py is:

```
from rest_framework import serializer
from basics.models import Article

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=300)
    date = serializers.DateField()

def create(self, validated_data):
    return Article.objects.create(validated_data)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
    instance.author = validated_data.get('author', instance.author)
    instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
    instance.date = validated_data.get('date', instance.date)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

I call it in the terminal using  python manage.py shell as:

In [4]: from basics.serializers import ArticleSerializer

can someone please guide me what should be done

Comment: How, Where do you call this serializer show relevant code snippets?

Comment: I have added the information from where I call this serializer

Comment: does this error occur when you import it in views.py or in some other files?

Comment: this error is occurring when in the terminal when I'm using it by Django shell

Comment: What is your project directory structure? What are other internal imports inside the basics app (imports from basics in basics app)? What is the result of `python manage.py check` command? Does this exception occur when running the basics app differently, for example via `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: I think it should be from basics.serializer import ArticleSerializer not basics.serializers. Is it a spelling mistake?

Comment: Your file is named `serializer` and you try to import `serializers` which doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be from basics.serializer import ArticleSerializer not basics.serializers. Is it a spelling mistake?